# STM32 + LWIP - Pbuf Configuration

Tags: stm32, lwip

I'm now working with LWIP+STM32 and now trying to get http GET/POST from browser. So basically, the connection is good and I did receive the packet with the below code:

```
if((err = netconn_recv(conn, &inbuf)) == ERR_OK) {

      netbuf_first(inbuf);

      do{

          netbuf_data(inbuf, (void**)&buf, &buflen);
          //recieve_buffer=concat(recieve_buffer,buf);
          DBGSTR("%d",i);
          i++;
          }while(netbuf_next(inbuf) >= 0);
}
```

But somehow it doesn't receive the whole packet, the do-while loop always runs once even if the receive buffer is super big. I check the wireshark and the content body did send. I guess it is because of the pbuf is not enough to allocate. But anyone has idea about what to do for pbuf configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of LWIP stack can be found in lwip_opt.h header file. The size of pbuf buffer is defined by macro PBUF_POOL_BUFSIZE. Compare it with the size of your payload.

Also be aware that the packet can be fragmented if it's too big so the data will be stored in multiple pbufs.